# Android dp vs px for layout and graphics

Tags: android-layout, graphics

I m trying to understand how android draws graphics and layout.

I come from web world (css, html, and so on) where all is in px, %, em, etc...
Android instead uses dp and this make me confused.

from official guide:

> Density-independent pixel (dp)
>   A virtual pixel unit that you should use when defining UI layout, to express layout dimensions or position in a density-independent way.
>   The density-independent pixel is equivalent to one physical pixel on a 160 dpi screen, which is the baseline density assumed by the system for a "medium" density screen. At runtime, the system transparently handles any scaling of the dp units, as necessary, based on the actual density of the screen in use. The conversion of dp units to screen pixels is simple: px = dp * (dpi / 160). For example, on a 240 dpi screen, 1 dp equals 1.5 physical pixels. You should always use dp units when defining your application's UI, to ensure proper display of your UI on screens with different densities.

[linked image, simple layout with two columns and four rows](http://tinypic.com/r/34pm9n7/5)

If I want create a layout like this (see linked image) where white blocks are views (buttons, for example) and colored blocks are image. How can I proceed?

How big should my images be to fit in half screen?

Sorry for my english.. I'm trying to learn also that ;)

Thank you in advance

Comment: check this out:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2025282/difference-between-px-dp-dip-and-sp-in-android